# React.js Trying to access the response of an API fetch that works and returns data in my /api but I cannot access in my /src/

Tags: javascript, reactjs, async-await

I think I am probably missing something pretty simple.

in src/api/index.js I have the following:

```
  export async function loginUser(username, password) {
    try {
      const response = await fetch(`${BASE}/users/login`, {
          method: "POST",
          headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json'
          },
           body: JSON.stringify({
             user: {
               username: username,
               password: password
             }
           })
        })
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(result => {console.log(result)
          const key = result.data.token
          localStorage.setItem('stToken', JSON.stringify(key))
          localStorage.setItem('username', JSON.stringify(username))
        })

          
      
        return response
      
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
    }
  }
```

My loginUser is being called in my onSubmit handler in my src/component/login.js

```
const submitHandler = async (event) => {
    event.preventDefault()
    setUserData( {username, password})

    const response = await loginUser(username, password)
    alert({response})
    console.log(response.data)
    
  }
```

This API call returns from the loginUser function, when called by onSubmit:

```
{success: true, error: null, data: {…}}
data: {token: 'eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJfaWQiOiI2M…TU2fQ.4l7g5y8hlEDxlmkWUPiVIfM6XWCqHa0410QXGLy72vw', message: 'Thanks for logging in to our service.'}
error: null
success: true
[[Prototype]]: Object
```

However, whatever I try to access the return data from the submitHandler (such as console.log or any variation of response.data.token I try, I just get null. As of right now the only way for me to access any API returns in my API folder are via local storage.

Please help me identify what i am missing.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you are using both *promises* (`.then`) and *async await*.

When you `await` the `fetch.then.then` you actually awaits for the last returned value. In your case, since you return nothing (`undefined`) from your last `.then`, you can't access the data.

Try return the result -

```js
const response = await fetch(`${BASE}/users/login`, {...})
  .then(response => response.json())
  .then(result => {console.log(result)
     const key = result.data.token
     localStorage.setItem('stToken', JSON.stringify(key))
     localStorage.setItem('username', JSON.stringify(username))
     return result; // this is the line I added
   })
```

Comment: Thank you so much. I have been staring at this for a day and I have it flowing now.

Comment: @DavidStein can u please mark the asnwer as correct?